# Create menu tree starting from a certain parent ID

Tags: php, menu, tree

I have a db table layout similar to one which example of is here
http://blog.ideashower.com/post/15147134343/create-a-parent-child-array-structure-in-one-pass

I also applied code from that site to create full tree of menu items

However, I'm completely stuck on how to modify the script when I want to start printing the tree out from selected parent. So, using table example from that link, I want to be able to show a subtree of North America menu item (but not show North America itself). I know I would need to pass a paramater (parent ID) into that function and the manipulate $thisref array but I'm stuck on how exactly

```
$refs = array();
$list = array();

$sql = "SELECT item_id, parent_id, name FROM items ORDER BY name";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($data = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

 $thisref = &$refs[ $data['item_id'] ];
 $thisref['parent_id'] = $data['parent_id'];
 $thisref['name'] = $data['name'];

 if ($data['parent_id'] == 0) {
     $list[ $data['item_id'] ] = &$thisref;
 } else {
     $refs[ $data['parent_id'] ]['children'][ $data['item_id'] ] = &$thisref;
 }
}
```